# How to flatten array of objects in jq

Tags: json, jq, distinct-values

I have an array of objects in a json file:

```json
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "LOCATION": {
        "NAME": "Dallas"
      }
    },
    {
      "LOCATION": {
        "NAME": "New York"
      }
    },
    {
      "LOCATION": {
        "NAME": "Dallas"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to to iterate over the objects and get a **unique list** of names.

**In this example, the desired output** would be `["Dallas", "New York"]`

How do I do this? I have tried the following but it fails:

```bash
jq '.Items | map({LOCATION}) | .unique_by(.NAME)' file.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unique_by` lets you obtain higher-level items (the objects in this case) staisfying a lower-level condition (uniqueness in this case). But you only want the unique array itself, so `unique` already does the job:

```bash
jq '.Items | map(.LOCATION.NAME) | unique'
```

```json
[
  "Dallas",
  "New York"
]
```